# WordPress site does not detect 404 page after adding question mark just after website URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

my website framework is WordPress and it's not detecting 404 page after adding question mark just after website URL.  i.e www.mydomain.com/?abc

it's showing home page instead of showing 404 page. how can I fix this issue, please help me to get out this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Why do you find this as a problem? It's normal behavior, the question mark 'signalize' for beginning of a query string, that is passed to the server along with the request and its not a part of the path or the domain name. So in other words www.mypage.com/?(www.mypage.com/index.php?) is a valid request without any parameters/query passed to the server, there is no logic to expect 404 error (Not found). Everything is normal and behaving as expected and I don't see any reason for your worries - [check this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the website is showing home page when I accessing these type of URL .. i.e websitename.com/?strategic=dissertation-strategic-leadership websitename.com/?stalin=terror-essay-stalin

these types of URLs should be showing 404 not found page ..!

Comment: ok that's different from what you wrote in first place. Does your theme have a 404.php page ?

Comment: Yes, if I try to access non-existing page i.e. websitename.com/abcd, then it shows default 404 not found page of the theme.